# How do you say (something) 'could be'/'might be' the cause/reason for a certain effect/situation?

Tags: grammar, english-to-japanese, phrase-requests

I was searching for a way to say something like the following:

"I think that's why he was crying."

I remember かもね or simply かも being used to suggest something 'could be'/'might be', but I'm not sure if it fits in this context.

Would the following be a correct translation?

"泣いていた理由かもね。"

What are correct ways to say something 'could be'/'might be' the cause, in Japanese?

Comment: かも derives from the grammar structure かもしれない。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "I think that's why he was crying."
>   "泣いていた理由かもね。"

You're right that ～かも（ね） means "could be / might be" (You could also say 「～かもしれない（ね）」) and your translation makes sense (though I'd probably say more like 「それが泣いていた理由かもね。」), but I think it'd sound more natural if you said it as...

> だから泣いていたのかもね。